# Why does key binding cause Emacs to execute my function on startup?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I have a function in my Emacs `init.el` file that lets me rebuild and byte-compile it from a literate source file. It consists of a `lambda` function wrapped by `defun` and works exactly as I expect. So far, so good.

```lisp
(defun tangle-init-and-reload ()
  "Tangle the code blocks in init.org, byte-compile, and reload."
  (lambda ()
    (interactive)
    ;; Don't run hooks when tangling.
    (let ((prog-mode-hook nil))
      (org-babel-tangle-file (concat user-emacs-directory "init.org"))
      (byte-compile-file (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el"))
      (load-file user-init-file))))
```

When I read about functions in Elisp, it appears to me that I should be able to simply use `defun` to define a named function and skip the `lambda`, so I removed the `lambda` and otherwise left the function intact, like so:

```lisp
(defun tangle-init-and-reload ()
  "Tangle the code blocks in init.org, byte-compile, and reload."
  (interactive)
  ;; Don't run hooks when tangling.
  (let ((prog-mode-hook nil))
    (org-babel-tangle-file (concat user-emacs-directory "init.org"))
    (byte-compile-file (concat user-emacs-directory "init.el"))
    (load-file user-init-file)))
```

Written this way, the function also works as expected -- as long as I call it with `M-x tangle-init-and-reload RET`. If I assign it a key binding, it executes on startup with one of two different side effects: With some key bindings, it attempts to overwrite `init.elc` while Emacs still has it open, and with others it successfully overwrites `init.elc`, but then re-executes on reload, causing an infinite recursion.

I'm perfectly happy to stick with the `lambda` version, which has no issues with key binding, but I would like to understand what magic `lambda` is performing and/or what it is about key binding that causes the second version to execute at startup. Can anybody explain?

For whatever it's worth, my key bindings are in a custom minor mode like so:

```lisp
(defvar custom-map (make-keymap)
  "Custom key bindings.")
(define-key custom-map (kbd "C-c C-i") (tangle-init-and-reload))
(define-minor-mode custom-bindings-mode
  "Activates custom key bindings."
  t nil custom-map)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the key binding, you associate a key to a value, which in your case is:

```
(tangle-init-and-reload)
```

This is an expression that is evaluated normally, ie. you call the function when you associate the binding.

In the previous version, evaluating the same function returned a closure, you had one level of indirection, so you established a binding from a key to the function returned by the call to `tangle-init-and-reload`.

You can simply give the name of the function associated with the binding, by quoting it:

```
(define-key custom-map (kbd "C-c C-i") 'tangle-init-and-reload)
```

Comment: Well that couldn't be more simple and straightforward, could it? And with that you answered two other questions that were rattling around in my head. Thanks for the very clear and logical explanation!